# React Native iOS Module plugin - using @import in m+ file

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

error: Use of '@import' when C++ modules are disabled, consider using -fmodules and -fcxx-modules

Using in : In a static library (react native iOS module), I have m+ file. Using an external framework with @import.

Tried so far : Build Settings:

- Enable Module(c and objective - c) = yes
- Link Frameworks Automatically = yes
- Other c++ flags = -fcxx-modules -fmodules

Still not working. Though these solution works on the project but not for the library.

Edit:
Resolved - in the pod spec file I have to add the build settings:

s.xcconfig = {

```
  'OTHER_CPLUSPLUSFLAGS' => '-fcxx-modules -fmodules'
```

}

Comment: I got it. In the pod spec file I have to add the build settings.
s.xcconfig = {
      
      'OTHER_CPLUSPLUSFLAGS' => '-fcxx-modules -fmodules'
  }